# Plotting real-time graph with Microsoft Chart?

Tags: c#, mschart

I have started to draw graphs using [Microsoft Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_shared_tools#Graph). I managed to draw a simple line chart. I have one problem now is that in the background my database is being populated with real-time data, and I would like to show that on my line graph. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

For showing real-time data in the graph, you have to update it after each constant interval of time. This you can easily do through running a new thread for retrieval of data and a delegate for updating data in the graph.

Create a new thread with AddDataThreadLoop() as ThreadStart and use a delegate for adding data to the graph, for example, AddData():

```
addDataThreadStart = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadStart);
addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);
addDataRunner.Start();
```

In the functions, divide the total job as:

```
Private void AddDataThreadLoop() { //Retrieve data here}
Public void AddData() { //Update graph }
```

You can download the demo code [here](http://super0009.blogspot.in/2012/06/introduction-is-utility-based-on-ping.html).

Comment: The above answer is sufficient to clear the logic to solve your problem but if you need full code, you can download it from [here](http://super0009.blogspot.in/2012/06/introduction-is-utility-based-on-ping.html)